# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" как можно исправить?

Tags: c#

Выдает такую ошибку. суть задания в заданной квадратной матрице матрица вставляет 0 в элементы слева от главной диагонали и 1 в элементы справа от диагонали.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columns");
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] matrix = new int[n, m];
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter {n * m} items");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < matrix.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j < i)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = 0;
                }
                if (j > i)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = 1;
                }
                Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]} ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix.Length` - это общее число элементов, то есть `n * m`. И все-таки с нуля здесь надо перебирать элементы, а не с `1`.

Надо так.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```